# data capture using CDC

Tags: cdc, change-data-capture

To capture the deleted user name I had added a new column in my CDC table (eg:- cdc.dbo_testCDC_CT) to set the logged SQL user name.
ie; ALTER TABLE cdc.dbo_testCDC_CT ADD username VARCHAR(20) DEFAULT(SUSER_SNAME())). 
The value coming in that column is always "sa", but I am logged as windows authentication. Why this happing?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should never be modifying the system tables generated by cdc. This table was generated when you enabled cdc on your dbo.testCDC table and will include the columns of your source table, plus 5 additional columns, whose meaning is described here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb500305(v=sql.110).aspx. It will be deleted automatically when you disable cdc from your table.

I recommend reading up on cdc and the intended usage patterns first. A good start could be this article:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2008.11.sql.aspx

To answer your question why sa was always assigned to your column: all rows in the *_CT tables are filled by the log reader process which happens to run under the sa account in your case. This is not the way to add auditing to your system. The previously mentioned article can give you some pointers on better ways to implement auditing too.

Comment: @Sreepathi, please use the mark as answer button to reward the people that spent time answering your questions.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution should be capturing the 'Changed By' or 'Inserted By' Logged User Name and persisting that to the underlying data table subject of the capture instance itself. In that way your CDC Instance will also capture the logged User Name  for you.

As already mentioned, you should NEVER change the system-generated tables, for two simple reasons:
1. When they are restored for any reason, your changes will be lost
2. Changing system tables can provide you with quite unintended consequences.

Hope this might assist.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than changing the CDC table change the base table (Main source table for default value set  DEFAULT(SUSER_SNAME())) COLUMN you will get the user who deleted , or inserted and updated